# 5 million records sort txt file (not using any technique)?

Tags: c#

I have a file with 5 million records which are include of numbers
that they are out of sequence (irregular)
you can find file structure below :

```
 for instance          desired Result
------------          ---------------      
 723,80                1,4   
 14,50                 1,5 
 723,2                 10,8
 1,5                   14,50 
 10,8                  723,2 
 1,4                   723,80
```

This structure displays bad condition and optimum condition and I
expect to reach the optimum

The most important (the main) tip :
I didn't use any tecniques such as linq, ....
I want to do it with available algorithms and arrange the file.

furthermore (more over) the time should be considered
so, we need to use a proper algorithm to put the numbers in order
under a minute

Comment: Not really clear what exactly you're asking for, in that you've supplied no code as to what you've tried and what is/isn't working correctly.  This is pretty much required, so we can know how you are trying to work around it right now.

Answer (score 2):

You have several possible reasonable answers.

If you have enough memory, you get bring everything into memory, using a standard collection class, write your own comparison function and call sort.

If you have don't, you can write a polyphase merge sort (look it up), or write an ad-hoc method based upon a deeper understanding of your data

You can use a database as a sort, i.e., bulk insert the parsed data with and retrieve it with with the appropriate order by clause.

Buy or or download an existing sort that can handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

The best available sorting around the world is having n * log(n) complexity[n is the number of elements on your array]. One of such sorting algorithm named is [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). You can implement this sorting from your c# code and perform the sorting(only if when there is no built in quick sort available in c#).

Another option can be, performing the sorting in c/c++. Read the whole file in an array. And then perform the [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) function over the array with custom compare function (that is written by yourself, and passed to qsort()). Convert the c/c++ code into a dll and call this from your c# code.

Comment: Not quite true. qsort is the best if you sort only by comparison (less,equal,greater). In some cases you can use a radix sort which can  sort order kN -- not appropriate in all cases (k can be very large or use too much memory), but can be much faster when it is appropriate